# how to write data to azure storage tables

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I have data which needs to be written to azure storage tables.
Can someone point me to a blog or msdn article where I can refer the sample code?
Help me proceed beyond the 4th line of code.

```
        string tableName = "myTable";
        CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("ConnectionString");
        CloudTableClient cloudTableClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        cloudTableClient.CreateTableIfNotExist(tableName);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [Azure Platform Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=413e88f8-5966-4a83-b309-53b7b77edf78&displaylang=en). In particular, look at the lab called ExploringWindowsAzureStorageVS2010. That lab will walk you through creating a table entity, creating a table context, and code to insert into table storage, including the use of AddObject() and SaveChanges() to write your entities to a table.

Answer (score 0):

I also found a good blog at http://www.geekzone.co.nz/vs2008/6311

Comment: That blog post was published in mid-2009, several months before official storage support came out in the SDK, and it's based on a sample storage client library that's no longer available.